# Qt Deployment on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qml

My Qt is 4.8.5 and I plan to deployment a Qt application on other Mac osx10.9,but when i use otool tools to check app and so on,but copy the application to other mac osx, we get the error:dyld: Library not loaded: .QtDeclarative.framework/version/4/QtDeclarative
  Referenced from: /Users/.../xx.app/Contents/MacOS/xx
  Reason: image not found
this is all  thanks

Comment: Have you tried `macdeployqt` as well? Have you seen the answer here? Have you tried that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061354/deploying-qt-frameworks-with-mac-app-and-usage-of-otool

Comment: There are some issues with Qt4.8.5 and Mac OSX 10.9. A major one is probably the issues with codesining (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32896) and this is need from 10.9 (http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/).
What I did was compile Qt5.2 to staticlibs, link them to the app, and codesign the libs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use macdeployqt.

```
macdeployqt yourApp.app -verbose=2 -dmg
```